# Get count of all users including deleted users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my ruby on rails application, I want to get `count` of all `users` and I am doing something like below:

```
@user = User.count
```

It gets me result of all users that are not deleted but I want to get count of all users including `users who were deleted + users those who aren't deleted`.

Comment: If users have been deleted, they are no longer in the database, therefore you can not count them

Answer (score 1):

```
@user = User.count
```

Here User is database table if user is deleted before count then `.count` will not count those user because they are no longer available in your current app database.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the count as a rough stimation, you might check the last id of your users table.

This will not be accurate if the users that were deleted are always the last that were inserted, but this gives you an idea about it.

```
User.last.id
```

would do the trick.

Why this is an stimate?

Suppose that the last inserted user in your database has id = 499.
If you insert a new user it will take id = 500. (At this point `User.last.id` returns 500)

Iif you delete the one with id = 500, your last id will be 499, but if you insert a new one, it will take the id = 501 (this is true for mysql, no idea for the other database systems)

But this is not ensuring that you ever had 501 users simultaneously existing in the database: It only means that there were 501 insertions in the users table as long as it has never been truncated (because a truncation resets the id counter to 0)

Comment: What's the point of having an estimation when you can get the exact value for the same "cost"?

Comment: It's an estimation because that count will not be exact in case the lasts inserted users are deleted. It could be possible to query the db to know which is the current id count... if you find how to do that feel free to edit the answer

Comment: @Fer `User.last.id + 1`

Answer (score 0):

To have the expected result you could use this gem [paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia)

With this gem when you delete a User it will be delete logically and not from database, this way you can get the amount of users properly. Take a look at readme for more details.